# Changing body css style property from AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new to AngularJS and have made a directive which, on window scroll, is supposed to modify a value in the css style of the `body` tag. This is the directive:

```
app.directive("parallaxDir", function ($window, $document) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function () {
            console.log('Scroll in da directive');
            // Here I want to modify the body tag css style to:
            // background-position-y = $window.pageYOffset / 2) + "px")
        });
    };
});
```

How do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon a solution at: 
http://corpus.hubwiz.com/2/angularjs/16725136.html

The final code looks like this:

```
app.directive("parallaxDir", function ($window, $document) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function () {
            var body = angular.element(document).find('body');
            body.css("background-position-y", ($window.pageYOffset / 2) + "px");
            scope.$apply();
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but the jqLite `find` method in the accepted answer has to search through all of the children where as the `body` is stored directly on the `$document`. It would be more efficient to use `$document[0].body`.

Your final code would look like this:

```
app.directive("parallaxDir", function ($window, $document) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function () {
            var body = $document[0].body;
            body.css("background-position-y", ($window.pageYOffset / 2) + "px");
            scope.$apply();
        });
    };
});
```